# ReadFile function returning error code 50 - Request not supported

Tags: c++, c, windows

I want to read the data received by the network adapters by calling the "ReadFile" API. I got the handle from the CreateFile function. When I call the ReadFile with the obtained handle, it is always returning the error code 50 (Request not supported).

I see in the WinObj tool for the network adapter driver and it is showing that it supports (Read/Write). I searched online but could not exactly figure out what is causing the issue.

```
DWORD lpNumberOfBytesRead = 0;
char   buf[1600] = { 0 };
size_t size = 1522;
HANDLE hFile;


hFile = CreateFile("\\\\.\\{7A1C62D4-2FE2-49D6-9090-DFA5FF1F8395}", GENERIC_WRITE | GENERIC_READ, 0, 0, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM , 0);
if (hFile == TUNFD_INVALID_VALUE) {
    int errcode = GetLastError();
    DisplayError(errCode);
    return -1;
}

if (ReadFile(hFile, buf, (DWORD)size, &lpNumberOfBytesRead, NULL) == 0) {
    int errcode = GetLastError();
    DisplayError(errCode);
    return -1;
}
```

Attached
[WinObj screenshot showing access permission](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kto3l.png)

Comment: I can't find any documentation for `TUNFD_INVALID_HANDLE` and the documentation for `CreateFile` says that on fail it returns `INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE`. It may be that you haven't correctly opened the file in the first place?

Comment: The other thing is the use of `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_SYSTEM` which the docs seem to only that anything with this attribute can ONLY be controlled by the OS. This may not be the case but take a look into that too.

Comment: your screenshot is showing 7C06...and your code is for 7A1c...I assume the permissions are the same though.  Are you running this as administrator?

Comment: bitbangs: I have two adapters. Both are having the same permissions and the user account is also having administrator privileges. Program is also run as administrator.

Comment: TheBeardedQuack: That is because I am using a sample which is having its own invalid handle defined. I checked the handle value after calling the CreateFile and I am sure that it is opening the file without any issues.

Comment: This is a [Deserialized NDIS Miniport](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/deserialized-ndis-miniport-drivers) device. It doesn't get read from directly like this. It supports a few I/O requests (implemented by ndis.sys) for management of the device interface, such as create, close, and I/O control. But most of the IRP major functions, including `IRP_MJ_READ`, are set to `ndis!ndisDummyIrpHandler`, which simply returns `STATUS_NOT_SUPPORTED`.

Comment: See [receiving network data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/receiving-network-data) and [sending network data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/network/receiving-network-data) for diagrams relating a protocol driver to the NDIS driver (providing the `Ndis*` API) to the Miniport driver (providing `Miniport*` functions that NDIS calls).